# Proximity Alert Receiver does not fire

Tags: android, proximity

I am creating proximity alerts for dynamically created overlays but I have a problem that the Broadcast receiver doesn't fire when the user moves within the radius.

```
private void registerIntents() {
    for(int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++) {
        double intentLat, intentLon;
        intentLat = (int)(points.get(i).getLat() * 1E6);
        intentLon = (int)(points.get(i).getLon() * 1E6);
        setProximityAlert(intentLat, intentLon, i+1,i);
    }
}
private void setProximityAlert(double lat, double lon, final long eventID, int requestCode)
{
    // 100 meter radius
    float radius = 100f;

    // Expiration is 10 Minutes (10mins * 60secs * 1000milliSecs)
    long expiration = 600000;

    LocationManager locManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    int uniqueID = requestCode;
    String intentAction = PROXIMITY_INTENT_ACTION + uniqueID;

    //Intent intent = new Intent(PROXIMITY_INTENT_ACTION);

    //intent.putExtra(ProximityAlertReceiver.EVENT_ID_INTENT_EXTRA, eventID);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), uniqueID, new Intent(intentAction), PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    mIntentFilter = new IntentFilter(intentAction);
    locManager.addProximityAlert(lat, lon, radius, expiration, pendingIntent);
}
```

This is the code for creating the proximity alerts and the following code is for registering the Broadcast Receiver. I have it in the on create method.

```
        this.registerIntents();
    registerReceiver(new ProximityAlertReceiver(), mIntentFilter);
```

I would really appreciate any help with this as I've been working on it for days with no success.

These are the permissions I have in my manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're using a broadcast intent rather than a directed intent?  Have you declared the proper permissions in your manifest to receive location data?  Are you sure location data is being generated at all?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by broadcast intent vs directed intent.  I'm pretty new to Android and I found several tutorials that used this code so I assumed it was the way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the PendingIntent that goes directly to your class:

```
    Intent i = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, i, 0);
```

This skips the step of going through a BroadcastReceiver and simplifies the code.  If you're still not seeing the notifications, then I'd check to make sure the LocationManager is generating any position updates at all.

Comment: This didn't work.  I think I need to start over. would you know of a simple proximity alert tutorial that lays out what I need to do. I keep finding random code that isn't explained. Thank you for trying to help me.

Comment: Have you tried this [tutorial](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-proximity-alerts-tutorial.html)

Comment: It would be helpful to add an answer yourself which explains what it was that was going wrong, in case someone else stumbles across this question with the same problem.